# geocode on one of multiple attribute changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

with Rails `geocoder` gem  the geocoding is run as a callback on the model.
To avoid hitting uselessly the geocoding API service, this callback needs to be conditional on one of the key attributes to forming an address for geocoding; these are saved to the database (`address`, `municipal_id`, `postcode`, `region_id`, `nation_id`).

Defining a virtual attribute combining those values

```
def inserted_address
  [self.address, self.municipal.name, self.postcode, self.region.try(:name), self.nation.name].compact.join(', ')
end
```

will not play with ActiveRecord's dirty module, as it is apparently only acting upon database-written  values.  So `obj.inserted_address.changed?` is not a solution.
But the following method on the class

```
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.inserted_address.present? and (obj.address.changed? or obj.postcode.changed? or obj.municipal_id.changed?) }
```

returns a complaint that `undefined method 'changed?' for "my street, 114":String`

How can this statement be then composed?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear are you saying `address`, `postcode`, and `municipal_id` are not stored in the database?

Comment: No, those are stored (question updated).  it is the class defined attribute `inserted_address` that is not saved.

Comment: Unless I am missing something `inserted_address` has nothing to do with the question you can just go with `if: ->(obj){ [:address,:postcode,:municipal_id].any? {|attr| obj.public_send("#{attr}_changed?") }}`

Comment: yes, , the virtual attibute `.changed?` was a discarded avenue. Your syntax worked its wonder.